# Add folders to SVN using ANT

Tags: svn, ant, tortoisesvn

I would like to add folders to the below mentioned URL, Without checking out any single file locally. Is it possible?

```
URL hostname ":" port/uk/components/trunk/
```

I need to create the below folder structure under trunk.

```
Pro_abc--> deploy ---> BW 
       --> Common ---> project
                  ---> jars
                  ---> data_files
```

Comment: Sorry guys not able post URL properly, because it was giving some error. URL "http://hostname:port/uk/components/trunk"

Comment: read the error. you need more reputation with the site before you're allowed to post urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout using the "[sparse checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html)" feature of SVN that allows you to fetch part of a repository - particularly a directory without any of its contents. Then you can add folders to the working copy and commit them (if that's what you want), or you can fetch the root directory and then repeat with the desired directories.

Comment: Super, i need the same what you mentioned. Could you please provide any example or code or url, I can implement the "sparse checkout". NOw i need to implement the same in code using ANT.